# JSDoc does not work in local package in a Lerna monorepo project using webpack dev server but works when released to package registry

Tags: reactjs, webpack, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, lerna

Github Project repo:
https://github.com/Fralleee/lerna-intellisense-jsdoc-vscode

I have a monorepo project with two packages (Web & API). These are linked using Lerna. The Web project imports the API package, and the API requests are documented using JSDoc.

The documentation gets loaded perfectly if the API package is released and imported from NPM.
[image: working example]

However, if it is run locally via Lerna & Webpack dev server, the documentation is lost and only available in the local code (in the API folder).
[image: not working]

I have tried writing the documentation using modules and namespaces and searching for different types of solutions, but none seem to work.

The JSDoc and function:

```js
/**
 * Get comments from JSON placeholder API
 * @namespace API
 * @module
 * @param {GetCommentsRequestExample} input PostId
 * @returns {Promise.<GetCommentsResponseExample>} Array of comments
 */
export const getComments = input => apiGet('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments', input, GetCommentsRequest, GetCommentsResponse)
```

I can't figure out why the JSDoc works when the package is released but not when run locally.

---

**EDIT after 2 hours of extra testing**

I export everything using an index file in the API package. This index file imports everything from the package and then ships it like a single entry point.

If I define the function and JSDoc inside this index file directly, the JSDoc is available to other packages, even when run locally.

[image: two different approaches]

So it seems to be an issue with export -> import -> export again that messes up the JSDoc. This is not a solution since the Api-package has too much code to fit into a single file.

Comment: If you build one of your packages locally and restart your IDE does the JSDoc IntelliSense hinting start working properly?

Comment: @plasmid87 yes it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this exact problem with VSCode and Lerna. The solution was to add a `jsconfig.json` to the root of the monorepo (or wherever the `lerna.json` is located).

It happens because VSCode needs to be told it is supposed to look for hints in the `src/` directories of each package.  I think it looks for the file specified in the `main` property of `package.json` by default (so when the package is built, it can see hints in this file - obviously no good for development!)

Some assumptions for an example configuration below:

1. You have a `packages/` directory containing all your packages
2. Each package has a `src/` directory containing the code
3. Your packages have a namespace `@foo` (e.g., packages are called `@foo/API` or similar)

Add the following to `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@foo/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    }
  }
}
```

After restarting VSCode / re-opening the folder the IntelliSense hints should show up correctly. If you are not using a namespace for your packages you can add multiple lines to `paths` instead, explicitly pointing to the correct `src/` directory or use the `include` syntax [from the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig).

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Each package needs a `jsconfig.json` too, so that it knows how to resolve sibling packages properly, e.g.,

```
{
  ...
  "paths": {
    "@foo/*": ["../*/src"]
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this kind of resolved it. However not fully (maybe it isn't possible?).

The intellisense I get from the root jsconfig is not as detailed as the one I get from each package locally (each package has its own jsconfig aswell).
For example I can't use object as type definitions, also it seems to lose the return declaration from the intellisense.
https://i.imgur.com/ncH59GK.png


When you resolved your problems, did you happen to resolve these issues aswell?

I have tried removing each packages jsconfig, this only reduced the more detailed intellisense to the same used globally.

Comment: Unfortunately I think it's just the way the different "peek" functions work. I get the same behaviour when I hover (green in your screenshot) and then when typing the function (red in your screenshot). I just had a look at the VSCode docs and it looks like this is just the way VSCode does it: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_hover-information - have a look at the hover information vs signature help and I think it's the same as what we're seeing

Comment: Yeah, hover information displays more detail, however what I meant was that intellisense and hover detail information is lost when I hover a function from another package, but it's available if I hover inside the package.

Only thing available is the JSDoc but not the intellisense

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Sorry I haven't seen this problem before. It could be an extension changing the behaviour or maybe my setup has something different about it

Comment: Uploaded a very miniature/basic version of my repo to github if you would like to test it out and see.
https://github.com/Fralleee/lerna-intellisense-jsdoc-vscode

Comment: I just made a pull request - there was a missing step - each package also needs a `jsconfig.json` paths set - I'll update my answer

Comment: Hmm, the hover information from "requestFromIndex" was always available (declared in index) but the "requestFromSrc" isn't, and that is kind of the issue. Not sure if this solved it, it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197265/discussion-between-plasmid87-and-fralle).