# Why am I losing JSDoc type definitions when importing a React library into an Ember app in a monorepo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, ember.js, monorepo

I have two packages in a single repo, `charts` is for all of the charts and is built in React, while `ui` is for the rest of the UI and built in Ember.

Because the charts library is quite complicated, I decided to add JSDoc to each chart to expose the expected parameters to the UI library. To make this simpler, each chart is exported, then imported into a `index.js` file in the React app, which is then imported into the Ember app and consumed there.

The issue I'm facing is that I can see the type definition everywhere in the React app, but as soon as I import it into the Ember app, I lose all of the type definition on hover

I tried following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268405/jsdoc-does-not-work-in-local-package-in-a-lerna-monorepo-project-using-webpack-d) to no avail

Comment: can you share code / more information? does your ember project have a tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json? generally the LSP provider that shows JSDoc information, tsserver, needs one of those two files in a project in order to activate